# permission user and admin yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

excuse me I want to ask, about how to make permission rules from my user table in yii2 framework,
which I have a table named user.in it contains a column of positions with the contents "user" and "admin" I want to set that when logging in only my admin can upload files.
I want to know how to solve it??

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::class,
                'rulesConfig' => ['class'=> AccessRule::className()
            ],
                'only' => ['upload'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        // 'actions' => ["upload"],
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to use the PHPManager, which saves the roles within files.
Or the DBManager, which brings its own database tables where it stores the things.
There is a wonderful article by Yii that might help you, it explains everything in detail.

[Link to Guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization)